My MacBook Air M2 keyboard is completely non-functional
Last week my MacBook Air M2 keyboard and trackpad became completely unresponsive, and then the screen started flashing. After searching the internet for quick fixes to no avail I installed the Ventura version of macOS hoping this would clear up the issue. My trackpad is now operational, however, the keyboard is still dead. The screen has stopped flashing as well, at least for now.
The backlight on the keyboard works, the power button works, I was able to connect a usb keyboard which worked briefly but no longer works at login screen, but I can connect a Logitech Bluetooth keyboard that works in recovery mode only. Booting into Safe mode has revealed more of the same and I am able to access the terminal function while in recovery mode.
Any answers would be most appreciated, I am a full time online student and my Mac is my lifeline! Help! Ty in advance.

If it is a software issue, it's not the OS, but something you've added. Otherwise, it's a hardware issue.
